# 360° 3D top/down video player

Tags: 3d, video-player, vr

I cannot find a 360° 3D video player for 3D videos in over/under format on my GearVR or Windows Mixed Reality Headset. I recorded the videos with the InstaPro2 3D camera. There are lots of 360° players, but none in 3D it seems. Any suggestions?